# Threshold and practical requirements for initial state preparation?

Tags: quantum-state, noise, technical-standards, initialization

At the beginning of a quantum computational process we generally want to start in a perfectly known initial state, and evolve from there. This cannot be done perfectly, for fundamental reasons, but I strongly suspect there has to be a practical limit below which you are in a garbage-in-garbage-out situation.

My full question is not on this input fidelity threshold per se (although feel free to provide that too), but rather on **the factors to consider and minimum set(s) of requirements one needs to prepare a good-enough initial state** (maybe Di-Vincenzo-list style, but preferrably with some example numbers). Presumably the perfect answer has different sections, for example depending on whether one employs thermal initialization or algorithmic cooling.

For a little more context, this question is related with certain aspects of previous ones:

- [Are there measuring standards (and units) for the identification of qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/are-there-measuring-standards-and-units-for-the-identification-of-qubits) (what could this kind of prospective standards say about initialization in different platforms?)
- [Are true Projective Measurements possible experimentally?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/are-true-projective-measurements-possible-experimentally) (perfect projective measurements plus sufficiently coherent operations -including quantum error correction- would make good-enough initialization, but how do we deal with imperfect projective measurements?)
- [Is it true that observing a quantum state will end the superposition of states, and how not to observe?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/is-it-true-that-observing-a-quantum-state-will-end-the-superposition-of-states/) ("*How can i be sure my input was put in without looking?*")

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably late to party but I found this section today.
In terms to answer your question[s] I made a lot of thoughts and read enough paper for a tree.

I found 2 excellent experiments (very timely) that show their practical testing problems and solutions. And most important their preparation for a reproducible quantum state.
The documentations of both projects are really well written. I see no need of just copying and paste it here or describe it by myself and leaving out to many details.
I enjoyed reading it and will provide it to you for better preparation in the future.

---

**1. Project:** [Low-depth Quantum State Preparation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.07533.pdf#page=1) at 15 March 2021 (China)

This Team investigate this space-time tradeoff in quantum state preparation with classical data. Trying Positive label state preparation and Arbitrary state preparation.

---

**2. Project:** [Automatic Preparation of Uniform Quantum States
Utilizing Boolean Functions](https://si2.epfl.ch/%7Edemichel/publications/archive/2019/RC_fereshte.pdf) in 2019 (Switzerland)

The second Team investigate the
automatic state preparation of a specific subset of arbitrary
quantum states that are uniform superpositions over a subset of
basic states. Some of them can be represented using boolean functions.

Interesting at this project is that they found an upper bound on the number of quantum gates in the `{Ry(θ), CNOT}` gate set. In their experiment the quantum state preparation affords at most `2ⁿ − 1 Ry` rotation gates and `2ⁿ − 2` CNOTs

---

This answer is intended to provide an insight into practical quantum computing preparation and generate fix points to serve as reference and zero point.